# PHP Mysqli->query() returns false for SELECT INNER JOIN, Mysqli->error returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

EDIT: Added current data in use

I have a small functions file I've created as a database interface to be called for handling queries in a simple manner.

```
// Run SQL query
function runSQLQuery($sql) {
    // Open DB
    $db = connectToDB();

    if( $db->connect_errno ) {
        $data['response'] = false;

        $data['error_code'] = $db->connect_errno;

        $data['error'] = $db->connect_error;

        return $data;
    }

    // Run & return query
    $response = $db->query($sql);

    if( is_bool($response) ) {
        $response = ($response) ? 'true' : 'false';
    }

    switch($response) {
        case "true":
            $data['raw'] = $response;

            $data['response'] = true;

            $data['error'] = null;

            $data['id'] = $db->insert_id;

            return $data;

        case "false":
            $data['raw'] = $response;

            $data['response'] = false;

            $data['error_code'] = $db->errno;

            $data['error'] = $db->error;

            return $data;

        default:
            $data['raw'] = $response;

            $data['response'] = true;

            $data['error'] = null;

            if( $response->num_rows > 0) {
                while( $row = $response->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    $data['data'][] = $row;
                }
            }
            else {
                $data['data'] = null;
            }

            return $data;
    }
}

// Open database connection
function connectToDB() {
    // Connect to DB
    return new mysqli(
        DB_SERVER,
        DB_USER,
        DB_PASS,
        DB_NAME
    );
}
```

In most cases I'll build an SQL query somewhere else and pass it to this runSQLQuery function, then echo the response as JSON for my web-app.

I've had no issues with simple SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE commands, all have worked successfully. However I want to implement something slightly more complex for one function, a SELECT INNER JOIN query. The function building this query and executing is:

```
public function get($args) {
    extract($args);

    // Get event
    if(isset($userId)) {
        $sql =
        "SELECT j.id, j.event_address as address, j.event_datetime as datetime, j.event_note as note, j.event_price as price, j.client_id as userId, j.client_card_id as cardId, GROUP_CONCAT(p.event_package_id) as packages             
        FROM nr_jobs as j 
        INNER JOIN nr_job_packages as p ON p.event_id = j.id 
        WHERE j.client_id = $userId
        GROUP BY j.id;";
    }
    if(isset($jobId)) {
        $sql =
        "SELECT j.id, j.event_address as address, j.event_datetime as datetime, j.event_note as note, j.event_price as price, j.client_id as userId, j.client_card_id as cardId, GROUP_CONCAT(p.event_package_id) as packages             
        FROM nr_jobs as j 
        INNER JOIN nr_job_packages as p ON p.event_id = j.id 
        WHERE j.id = $jobId
        GROUP BY j.id;";
    }

    $events = runSQLQuery($sql);
    $events["sql"] = $sql;

    return $events;
}
```

For some reason running this specific query returns false. The JSON output I receive on my web app is

```
{
  "raw": "false",
  "response": false,
  "error_code": 0,
  "error": "",
  "sql": "SELECT j.id, j.event_address as address, j.event_datetime as datetime, j.event_note as note, j.event_price as price, j.client_id as userId, j.client_card_id as cardId, GROUP_CONCAT(p.event_package_id) as packages FROM nr_jobs as j INNER JOIN nr_job_packages as p ON p.event_id = j.id WHERE j.client_id = 1 GROUP BY j.id;"
}
```

If I run this query directly I actually get the correct results, several rows of data with a CONCAT column of packages as 1,2,3 as expected.

Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nr_jobs(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    event_address TEXT NOT NULL,
    event_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    event_note TEXT,
    event_price DECIMAL(13,4) NOT NULL,
    client_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    client_card_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES nr_clients(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (client_card_id) REFERENCES nr_payment_cards(id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nr_job_packages(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    event_package_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    event_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES nr_jobs(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (event_package_id) REFERENCES nr_packages(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Output of query run directly:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
| id | address                                                                       | datetime            | note | price     | userId | cardId | packages |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1 | SIM HQ LT3.02A, 461 Clementi Rd, Singapore, South West 59, Singapore          | 2018-11-28 10:38:00 |      |  320.0080 |      1 |      3 | 2,3      |
|  2 | Tay Eng Soon Library, Blk A, SIM HQ, Singapore, South West 59, Singapore      | 2018-11-28 10:42:00 |      |  320.0080 |      1 |      3 | 2,3,4    |
|  3 | SIM HQ Corporate Office, 461 Clementi Rd, Singapore, South West 59, Singapore | 2018-11-28 10:43:00 |      | 1020.0000 |      1 |      3 | 1,2,3,4  |
|  4 | L.A. City DOT, Los Angeles, California 90012, United States                   | 2018-11-28 12:15:00 |      |  860.0000 |      1 |      4 | 2,3,4    |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-----------+--------+--------+----------+
```

If the query has no issue, and other queries work within my function, why is this specific SELECT INNER JOIN query failing with no error?

EDIT:

nr_jobs data:

`SELECT * FROM nr_jobs;`

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
| id | event_address                                                                 | event_datetime      | event_note | event_price | client_id | client_card_id |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 | SIM HQ LT3.02A, 461 Clementi Rd, Singapore, South West 59, Singapore          | 2018-11-28 10:38:00 |            |    320.0080 |         1 |              3 |
|  2 | Tay Eng Soon Library, Blk A, SIM HQ, Singapore, South West 59, Singapore      | 2018-11-28 10:42:00 |            |    320.0080 |         1 |              3 |
|  3 | SIM HQ Corporate Office, 461 Clementi Rd, Singapore, South West 59, Singapore | 2018-11-28 10:43:00 |            |   1020.0000 |         1 |              3 |
|  4 | L.A. City DOT, Los Angeles, California 90012, United States                   | 2018-11-28 12:15:00 |            |    860.0000 |         1 |              4 |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+
```

nr_job_packages

`SELECT * FROM nr_job_packages;`

```
+----+------------------+----------+
| id | event_package_id | event_id |
+----+------------------+----------+
|  1 |                2 |        1 |
|  2 |                3 |        1 |
|  3 |                2 |        2 |
|  4 |                3 |        2 |
|  5 |                4 |        2 |
|  6 |                1 |        3 |
|  7 |                2 |        3 |
|  8 |                3 |        3 |
|  9 |                4 |        3 |
| 10 |                2 |        4 |
| 11 |                3 |        4 |
| 12 |                4 |        4 |
+----+------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Do you have data into nr_job_packages ?

Comment: @MarcoPens added in edit. Data is there and being retrieved correctly with a direct query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Previous function contained a typo.